# Counting lines from a plain text file that match a substring

Tags: batch-file, duplicates

I have a plain text file like below:

```
11/03/20 09:42:45 APP Service A stopped.
11/03/20 09:42:46 APP Starting service A.
11/03/20 09:42:46 APP Starting service A.
11/03/20 09:44:01 APP Service A stopped.
11/03/20 09:44:02 APP Starting service A.
11/03/20 09:44:02 APP Starting service A.
11/03/20 09:45:02 APP Service A stopped.

...
```

This file refers only to one service (service A). As you can see, lines that contains the "Starting" substring are duplicated twice each time.

Using a batch file (ms-dos bat file) I want to count the number of lines in the plain text file that contains the substring "Starting" but I do not want to count the duplicate ones.

For example, from below piece of plain text file and ignoring duplicated lines, I want the following output:

```
2
```

instead of (taking into account duplicated lines):

```
4
```

I know how to do this by taking into account the duplicated lines but not the ignoring them. I am performing below:

```
findstr /N "Starting" plain_text_file.txt | find /c ":"
```

Any ideas to not count the duplicated lines?

Maybe, once I have the result (number of lines) I can divide them by 2 but I do not think it is an elegant way to do it.

Comment: If the file is always as you've shown then dividing by two is the simplest method.  Batch files often rely on the format of the text being parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('^<file find "Starting"') do set "$%%a=7"
for /f %%a in ('set $') do set /a count+=1
echo(%count%
```

Comment: It is not working. When executed it says: environment variable $ not defined.

Comment: replace `file` with a real file name. And put in double quotes `"my log.txt`"

Comment: I have put it in double quotes but the same message appears.

Comment: so please let me take a look at your input file. Put it _packed_ (zip,rar,tar..) at a file hoster. Pastebin is not valid.

Comment: the problem is in the second for. Statement 'set $' seems to be not correct.

Comment: please provide your data, as I suggested earlier.

Comment: +1 Endoro's code works fine as long as your file has a line with `Starting` in it as you have listed in your question.  Try the log you posted in your question with Endoro's code.

Comment: Very very sorry, Yes! it works! I had a grammar mistake when searching for the string. Many thanks! Please, correct the last line because there is a mistake, it is: echo %count% open parenthesis should be removed.

Comment: Could you explain what it means $%%a=7? and what set $? could you explainme briefly the script please?

Comment: @user304602 to see, how it works put the command `set "$"` on the last line.